# How do I populate a String array using a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, populate

Please bear in mind that I am a beginner.
I have written the following code to try to populate a String array. It runs but will not print out the contents of the String array positions. (The same thing seems to work no problem for the double Array!)I do not understand why this is. If anyone could help me solve this problem I would be extremely grateful. See below for the code of the Main Class and a class called Fruit which contains the methods I am using.

```
`enter code here`Main class:
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fruit fruit = new Fruit();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of items in your shopping list:");
        int listSize = scanner.nextInt();
        String[] sl = new String[listSize];
        double[] price = new double[listSize];

        //Loop asking user to enter items and prices
        for(int i = 0; i <= listSize - 1; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter item " + (i+1) + ":");
            fruit.setName(scanner.nextLine());
            sl[i] = fruit.getName();
            scanner.next();

            System.out.print("Price of " + sl[i] + ":");
            fruit.setPrice(scanner.nextDouble());
            price[i] = fruit.getPrice();
         }
         //Loop printing items and their prices
         for(int i = 0; i <= listSize - 1; i++)
         {
             System.out.println(sl[i] + " cost " + price[i]);

         }
         //Order the array in ascending order so as to be able to easily 
identify the most and least expensive
        Arrays.sort(price);
        //Print out the most expensive and cheapest prices
        System.out.println("The most expensive item costs: " + 
price[price.length-1]);
        System.out.println("The least expensive item costs: " + price[0]);

    }
}

Fruit Class:

public class Fruit {
    private String name;
    private double price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
         this.price = price;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Scanner.readInt() and Scanner.readDouble() methods do not read the newline character after you press enter. However, the readLine() method reads the input that is skipped, so it reads the newline character. To fix the problem, you need to call scanner.readLine() after you call scanner.readInt() and scanner.readDouble() to get rid of the newline. Please see the code below.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fruit fruit = new Fruit();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of items in your shopping list:");
        int listSize = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine(); //calling nextLine() to get rid of the newline character
        String[] sl = new String[listSize];
        double[] price = new double[listSize];

        //Loop asking user to enter items and prices
        for(int i = 0; i <= listSize - 1; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter item " + (i+1) + ":");
            fruit.setName(scanner.nextLine());
            sl[i] = fruit.getName();

            System.out.print("Price of " + sl[i] + ":");
            fruit.setPrice(scanner.nextDouble());
            scanner.nextLine(); //calling nextLine() to get rid of the newline character
            price[i] = fruit.getPrice();
         }
         //Loop printing items and their prices
         for(int i = 0; i <= listSize - 1; i++)
         {
             System.out.println(sl[i] + " cost " + price[i]);

         }
         //Order the array in ascending order so as to be able to easily 
        Arrays.sort(price);
        //Print out the most expensive and cheapest prices
        System.out.println("The most expensive item costs: " + price[price.length-1]);
        System.out.println("The least expensive item costs: " + price[0]);

    }
}

class Fruit 
{
    private String name;
    private double price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
         this.price = price;
    }
 }
```

I have compiled and run this code, and here is the output it produces:

```
Enter the number of items in your shopping list:2
Enter item 1:
apple
Price of apple:1.25
Enter item 2:
bread
Price of bread:3.45
apple cost 1.25
bread cost 3.45
The most expensive item costs: 3.45
The least expensive item costs: 1.25
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: That is really helpful. Thank you so much! :D